# Unable to get Gif image frame count when get NSData of Gif Image fetched from iPhone

Tags: ios, ios8, frame, nsdata, gif

Unable to get Gif image frame count when get NSData of Gif Image fetched from iPhone

I am retriving Gif image from device and want to convert it to NSData, so that I can retrive frames of Gif.

Right now I am doing :

```
                CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(largeImage.CGImage);
                NSData* gifOriginalImageData = CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(provider));

                CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider(provider, NULL);
                size_t size = CGImageSourceGetCount(src);

or
                CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)gifOriginalImageData, NULL);
                size_t size = CGImageSourceGetCount(src);
```

But Here 'size' (Gif frames count) is coming 0 in every case.  **WHY?**

While if I load same Gif image from bundle

```
                NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"crad" withExtension:@"gif"];
                NSData* gifOriginalImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)gifOriginalImageData, NULL);
                size_t size = CGImageSourceGetCount(src);
```

It gives actual 'size' (Gif frames count)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
Byte buffer = (Byte)malloc(rep.size);
NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
```

fetch frames from this data